# Implementing the following algorithm for sorting

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting

I am writing this algorithm for a sort. I fail to see how it is different from insertion sort. I was wondering if someone can help me understand the difference. The current sort is written as insertion because I don't see the difference yet. This is homework, so I don't want an answer I want to understand the difference. The algorithm is [here](http://www.cs.rit.edu/~csci141/Homeworks/HwkE/PerkSort-Homework.pdf)

```
def file_open(perkList,fileName):


    with open(fileName, 'r') as f:
        for line in f.readlines():
            perkList.append(int(line))
def perkSort(perkList):
    for marker in range(len(perkList)):
        save = perkList[marker]
        i = marker
        while i < len(perkList) and perkList[i+1] > save:
            perkList[i] = perkList[i-1]
            i = i - 1
            perkList[i] = save
    print("New list",perkList)




def main():
     perkList = []
     file_open(perkList,'integers')
     file_open(perkList,'integers2')
     print("initial list",perkList)
     perkSort(perkList)

main()
```

Apologies that this question is not that clean. Edits are appreciated.

Comment: Please fix your indentation. Correct indentation is crucial for reading python code.

Comment: Sorry, editing right now.

Comment: Your assignment example looks more like Bubble sort and not insertion sort

Comment: I am trying to understand what it means to "percolate" the largest value to the top.

Comment: Yeah, this code doesn't implement insertion sort correctly yet. It doesn't even implement bubble sort correctly! It's like a funky combination of the two that I don't think will actually sort. Get insertion sort right first and it will be easy to explain the difference between insertion and percolation.

Comment: This does sort correctly. I have tested it and it does produce a sorted list of integers taken from a text file I created.

Comment: `initial list [32, 4, 5, 7, 6, 8, 7, 5, 1000, 4, 5, 777, 3, 39238, 44, 12414, 4, 325, 4, 4, 4, 2222]`
`New list [3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 7, 7, 8, 32, 44, 325, 777, 1000, 2222, 12414, 39238]` These are my results from a test

Comment: OK, you're right, it is insertion sort -- I apologize. I was thrown off by some of the indirection. (You could simplify this code a bit!) The difference between insertion and percolation is the difference between moving backwards in the list from `marker` and moving _forwards_ in the list from `marker`.

Comment: So insertion shifts down while percolation moves up?

Comment: Yes -- also, the way you handle `marker` is different, and the test for when to stop iteration changes. (Not wanting to give away everything!)

Comment: Thanks. I should be able to figure it out from here.

Comment: -1 for significantly altering the question "to avoid copying". The whole point of SO is that others can benefit from questions.

Comment: Sorry, I will put it back up then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perksort algorithm mentioned in your homework is essentially ***Bubble sort*** algorithm. What you have implemented is ***Inserion Sort*** algorithm. The difference is as follows:

## **Insertion Sort**

It works by inserting an element in the input list to the correct position in the list that is already sorted. That is it builds the sorted array one item at a time.

```
## Unsorted List ##
7 6 1 3 2

# First Pass
  7 6 1 3 2
# Second Pass
  6 7 1 3 2
# Third Pass
  1 6 7 3 2
# Fourth Pass
  1 3 6 7 2
# Fifth Pass
  1 2 3 6 7
```

Note that after *i* iterations the first *i* elements are ordered.

You have got maximum *i* iterations on *ith* step.

*Psuedocode:*

```
for i ← 1 to length(A)
  j ← i
  while j > 0 and A[j-1] > A[j]
     swap A[j] and A[j-1]
     j ← j - 1
```

This is what you did in your python implementation.

Some complexity analysis:

```
 Worst case performance       О(n2)
 Best case performance        O(n)
 Average case performance     О(n2)
 Worst case space complexity  О(n) total, O(1) auxiliary
```

## **Bubble Sort**

*This is **PerkSort Algorithm** given to implement in your homework.*

It works by repeatedly scanning through the list to be sorted while comparing pairs of elements that are adjacent and hence swapping them if required.

```
## Unsorted List ##
7 6 1 3 2

# First Pass
  6 1 3 2 7
# Second Pass
  1 3 2 6 7
# Third Pass
  1 2 3 6 7
# Fourth Pass
  1 2 3 6 7
# No Fifth Pass as there were no swaps in Fourth Pass
```

Note that after *i* iterations the last *i* elements are the biggest, and ordered.

You have got maximum *n-i-1* iterations on *ith* step.

I am not giving psuedocode here as this is your homework assignment.

*Hint:* You will move from *marker* in forward direction, in order to shift the elements towards up, just like bubbling

Some complexity analysis:

```
 Worst case performance       О(n2)
 Best case performance        O(n)
 Average case performance     О(n2)
 Worst case space complexity  О(n) total, O(1) auxiliary
```

#### Similarities

- Both have same worst case, average case and best case time
  complexities
- Both have same space complexities
- Both are in-place algorithms (i.e. they change the original data)
- Both are [Comparision Sorts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_sort)

#### Differences ( Apart from algorithm, of course )

Even though both algorithms have same time and space complexities on average, practically Insertion sort *is better* than Bubble sort.This is because on an average Bubble sort needs more swaps than Insertion sort. Insertion sort performs better on a list with small number of [inversions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_(discrete_mathematics)).

Comment: I think I got the answer and would like to verify it. I am going to post it up top for a brief moment then remove it to avoid others copying.

Comment: Or is it possible to direct message on stackoverflow?

Comment: I don't think there is an option for pm on stack overflow

Comment: Then I will quickly post it then remove it.

Comment: The top was changed. I plan to delete it all in 5 minutes to prevent copying.

Answer (score 0):

The program that you have written does implement insertion sort.

Lets take an example and see what your program would do. For input `5 8 2 7`

After first iteration

```
5 8 2 7
```

After second iteration

```
2 5 8 7
```

After third iteration

```
2 5 7 8
```

But the algorithm that is given in your link works differently. It takes the largest element and puts it in the end. For our example

After first iteration

```
5 2 7 8
```

After second iteration

```
2 5 7 8
```